# How to schedule Artisan commands in a package?

Tags: laravel, console, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a package that contains Artisan commands. I’ve registered these commands with Artisan via my service provider like so:

```
/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // Register Amazon Artisan commands
    $this->commands([
        'App\Marketplace\Amazon\Console\PostProductData',
        'App\Marketplace\Amazon\Console\PostProductImages',
        'App\Marketplace\Amazon\Console\PostProductInventory',
        'App\Marketplace\Amazon\Console\PostProductPricing',
    ]);
}
```

However, these commands need to be scheduled to run daily.

I know in **app/Console/Kernel.php** there is the `schedule()` method where you can register commands and their frequency, but how can I schedule commands in my package’s service provider instead?

Comment: Why can't you schedule them in the Kernel?

Comment: @MECU Because they are in a package, and not the Laravel application itself.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?  I'm facing the same issue now myself.

Comment: @sgrover No. I stopped working on this project. I think you could type-hint `Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule` in your service provider’s `boot()` method though, and add commands that way.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

(see Dave's answer below for Laravel 6.10+)

The trick is to wait until after the Application has booted to schedule the commands, since that is when Laravel defines the `Schedule` instance and then schedules commands internally. Hope this saves someone a few hours of painful debugging!

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

class ScheduleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->booted(function () {
            $schedule = $this->app->make(Schedule::class);
            $schedule->command('some:command')->everyMinute();
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Great find!

Comment: This only works in Laravel and not in Lumen (Lumen has no booted() method on the Application class).

Answer (score 24):

In Laravel 6.10 and above:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

class ScheduleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->callAfterResolving(Schedule::class, function (Schedule $schedule) {
            $schedule->command('some:command')->everyMinute();
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```